# Merge data from many excel files into single excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to merge data from 100+ excel files into single file using VBA where:

my repository (D:\rep) contain 100+ files with name of ( file1, file2 ...etc)
every excel file consist from 18 rows fixed in all excel files and having different number of columns, following sample of my excel files

[sample of excel files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfeQo.jpg)

i need to merge data from all those file into one file and combine the data as follow:

rows is still same in new file , 
column 1 is(file 1) column and its value refer to the sum of rows values as shown in the following figure

[sample of merged file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvRcG.jpg)

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how you want the data to be combined? In your example single file, each tool has multiple columns for different things (`cal`, `speedr`, `val` etc.), but in your example combined file there is just one column per tool per file. So should the cell `B2` in your combined file example be the sum of the range `B2:[x]2` from the individual file (where `[x]` is the furthest right column containing data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method much easier and better than VBA if the Excel 2010 version contains the right option ...

I've not used this with Excel 2010 but PowerQuery should be available as a free addin from Microsoft. If the 2010 addin version is anything like the current version of PowerQuery, you can easily create a query that loads all or some files from a folder and merges them.

PowerQuery is a point and click ETL (Extract, Transform and Load) tool for Excel and is both (fairly) easy to use and extremely powerful.

---

To do this in VBA is a lot more complex.

However, Microsoft provide some example code that might be used as a starting point

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim NRow As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range

    ' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet. 
    Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

    ' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\Peter\invoices\"

    ' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
    NRow = 1

    ' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

    ' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
    Do While FileName <> ""
        ' Open a workbook in the folder
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

        ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
        SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

        ' Set the source range to be A9 through C9.
        ' Modify this range for your workbooks. 
        ' It can span multiple rows.
        Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A9:C9")

        ' Set the destination range to start at column B and 
        ' be the same size as the source range.
        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
           SourceRange.Columns.Count)

        ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

        ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
        NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

        ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all 
    ' data is readable.
    SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg549168(v=office.14).aspx) for the full information.

There is also an example already on Stack:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313377/excel-vba-combine-multiple-workbooks-into-one-workbook

Comment: Julian Knight, thanks for your suggested code and tool, power query looking good but i'm not familiar, i will search about power query to perform my task

Comment: I've just updated another answer with similar details so you might want to look at that although that's for Office 2016.